# how to convert from unicode to utf8 in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

i'm trying to get **utf8** code from **unicode**. write now i have code that converts any INT to **unicode** but got stuck to proceed it to **UTF8**. any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you have tried sofar?

Comment: well actuolly i don't really know how to begin. so looking for information now

Comment: [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The function WideCharToMultiByte from Windows API will correctly do this for you. Here is the [WideCharToMultiByte reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx).

To Use the WideCharToMultiByte, you need select a code page. The common code pages are CP_ACP and CP_UTF8.
The CP_ACP is used to convert between ANSI and Unicode.
The CP_UTF8 is used to convert between UTF-8 and Unicode.

Here is a sample:

```
string UnicodeToUTF8( const wstring& str )
{
    char*     pElementText;
    int    iTextLen;

    // wide char to multi char
    iTextLen = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8,
         0,
         str.c_str(),
         -1,
         NULL,
         0,
         NULL,
         NULL );
   pElementText = new char[iTextLen + 1];
   memset( ( void* )pElementText, 0, sizeof( char ) * ( iTextLen + 1 ) );
   ::WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8,
         0,
         str.c_str(),
         -1,
         pElementText,
         iTextLen,
         NULL,
         NULL );
    string strText;
    strText = pElementText;
    delete[] pElementText;
    return strText;
}
```